# React Native External Stylesheet

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Is there a way in React Native that I can put all of my styles in a single file so it can easily be maintained (from my perspective) like in HTML we have a `.css` file.

And also I have a module where there are different styles based on a current user.

Answer (score 44):

You could simply create a Styles component like so with all your styles...

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native"

export default StyleSheet.create({
   ...
})
```

Then on any view needing styles, simply require it...

```
import styles from "./Styles"
```

Comment: Can't find variable: React

Comment: On which line? I noticed in my original response, I neglected to declare the variable as `const React` so I've edited it above.

Comment: @Coder that one has deprecated, use `import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'` instead.

Answer (score 25):

According to ECMAScript 6, correct way to export your styles would be like this.

style.js

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

export default StyleSheet.create({

container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20
},
welcome: {
    textAlign: 'center'
}
});
```

Then in your main JS file you can import like this.

```
import styles from './style'
```

Comment: you are missing the const key for CSS file. 

its should be 
export const styles = StyleSheet.create ({.....})

Comment: Yeah like @AnupGupta said you need to do `import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native'`, `const styles = StyleSheet.create({...styles...})`, and `export default styles;` within your stylesheet.js and then `import styles from './style'` in your main.js, but this is the closest / best answer.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can

- First create a file name style.js and create what ever style 
  you want like the following example:

Style.js

```
module.exports = {

    "centerRowAligment":{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor:"#a22a5f",
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems:"center"
    },
    "centerColumnAligment":{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }

}
```

Then in your react file just import it

```
import styles from './style'
```

And then use it in the render components

```
   <View style={styles.centerRowAligment}></View>
```

This should works fine !

Comment: The more modern/current way is to use "export default { ... }" instead of "module.exports = {...}" (at least if you compare it to the other components that are now out). Anyhow, this worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can try my project [rn-less](https://github.com/blackmiaool/rn-less).

It isolates your stylesheet from your jsx/js files with less.js.

And I have a [VS Code extension](https://github.com/blackmiaool/rn-less-helper) for it, with which you can jump between .less files and .js/.jsx files easily.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could add this module to your pipeline, and create a Gulp, or Webpack task to transpile the CSS into JavaScript.

> https://github.com/sabeurthabti/react-native-css

In my experience you're best of not using the same CSS for web and react native, because React Native's stylesheets don't actually cascade.

---

Or if you're willing to change your pipeline a little bit, PostCSS, which is a CSS4 to CSS3 transpiler, which supports all the features of SASS, can also be used to transpile, CSS to JavaScript

> https://github.com/postcss/postcss-js

Answer (score 2):

I agree to @Chris Geirman solution. you can just create stylesSheet as mention above by Chris and import to any view. In case if you want to merge external styleSheet to your individual view/component stylesheet then you can use ES6 new feature Object.assign like so:

styles = require('./StyleSheet');

const viewStyle = Object.assign(styles, StyleSheet.create({
    ...
 }); 
);

Answer (score 2):

The whole process of defining styles in my JavaScript caused me a lot of confusion when I first moved over to React Native from Ionic so I hope this helps...

Firstly, you've got to understand that React Native is **NOT** just an application running in a native WebView.  Rather than rendering divs and spans your JavaScript is actually producing higher-level, platform-specific components.

Therefore we can't apply the same styling rules (via external .css stylesheets) like you would a hybrid application written using another framework like Ionic.  Well not entirely anyway (see below).

Both options mentioned above are valid solutions.  Using:

- Separate JavaScript files to make your styles more modular; and
- Using libraries to transpile CSS to React Native StyleSheet objects.

**Note on latter option:**  Libraries like postcss-js won't enable you to use your CSS the way you normally would i.e. styling based on CSS selectors like .class and #id.  Styles will still need to be passed through to components via props.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on the latest React:

I have my stylesheet named CoolTextStyle.js (which is in the same directory as my index.ios.js). And it turns out you dont even need the 'StyleSheet' class

```
module.exports = 
{
  borderRadius:5
});
```

Then in index.ios.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput,TouchableHighlight,StatusBar } from 'react-native';

var cool_text_style = require('./CoolTextStyle');

export default class delme extends Component 
{
  render() 
  {
    return (
  <View>
    <StatusBar hidden={true} />
    <Text>Login</Text>
    <TextInput placeHolder='UserName' style={cool_text_style}></TextInput>
  </View>
)
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('delme', () => delme);
```

Answer (score 0):

none of above answer is perfect in view of segregation. It's a simple javascript require will give you answer for `Is there a way in React Native that I can put all of my styles in a single file`.

- Just create a folder and file. ex:- MyApp/cssstyle/StyleSheet.js
- then simple module.export the object contains screen names and corresponding styles.

```
const {StyleSheet} = require('react-native');

module.exports = {

  login: StyleSheet.create({
    bg1: {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
  home: StyleSheet.create({
    bg2: {
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    },
  profile: StyleSheet.create({
    bg3: {
      backgroundColor: 'green',
    },

  }),

};
```

- Now on your main screen(ex: login.js) where you want to apply your styles.
  `require your styles with proper StyleSheet path`. in my example it is `MyApp/cssstyle/StyleSheet`

```
const styles = require('MyApp/cssstyle/StyleSheet').login
```

then use it like

```
 <View style={styles.bgr}>
   ...
 </View>
```

That's all, by this way you can segregated the styles for different screens and in the mean time you can have all your styles in a single file.