# Is there any way to parse an existed css to React Native css?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to move my existed web app to mobile platforms. How should I transfer my existed css file to React Native css?

Is there any way to do this directly in the app logic, or I should use builders like webpack, if it so, which plugin do I need to use? Or maybe there is some packages for IDEs like Webstorm or Atom?

Any tip will be helpful, just not to do this manually.

Comment: Answer was found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595642/react-native-external-stylesheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into React Native to turn CSS into RN StyleSheets. React Native has a different set of attributes that is supports and some of them behave slightly different from their counterparts in CSS. That said I have a few suggestions for paths forward:

- Rewrite your css as StyleSheets as Sintylapse suggested [covered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595642/react-native-external-stylesheet)
- Use a third party transpiler [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595642/react-native-external-stylesheet) to convert yous css to React Native StyleSheets.
- Write all your styles inline with no stylesheets.

I would recommend the first option if you intend to work on this app or React Native in general for a while. Though it may be a bit rough to learn the syntax and how to write your styles, in the long run you will become more proficient than you would with the other methods. If you are looking for a good place to start with stylesheets [this blog post looks promising](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/intro-to-styling-in-react-native-c2c942bf1306). The transpiler could work but since it is a third party project I wouldn't be surprised if you ran into a bug and had to comb through generated code to find what is wrong. Writing styles inline can help prototype but it will not make it easy to maintain your app in the long run.