# Unable to import CSS file into React Project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I've just started using React for a change, and I've encountered an error that I can't seem to solve.

Everything works fine except that no matter what I do, React keeps throwing 'Can't resolve `./src/style.css`' or 'None of these files exist: `./src/style.css`.

My project structure is pretty strait forward:

```
App
    .expo
    .expo-shared
    assets
    node_modules
    src
        components
        screens
        style.css
    App.js

    ~everything else
```

My App.js contains this statement:
`import './src/style.css';`

I've also tried `require('./src/style.css');` but it doesn't work either.

Pretty sure I'm missing something humorously silly but still any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: And I've also tried restarting my development server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that you have .expo in your folder so I am assuming that you are using react-native.

For react native you have to style your component with **StyleSheet** and you won't be able to use *.css file.

check react-native styling documentation here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/style

Comment: @hanfani Is there a way I could convert my existing CSS file into React-Native SytleSheet?

Comment: Yes, you can use for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-to-react-native but you need to consider writing your next CSS using the recommended way from react-native as the converted CSS may behave unexpectedly in some cases.

Comment: consider also reading this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595642/react-native-external-stylesheet, it might be outdated a little bit but the ideas still valid, just to give you an idea how can you use the converted css.